# Python: dictionaries and string formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
phone_book = {
    'qazi': ['123-456-7890', 'qazi@qazi.com'],
    'bob': ['345-654-4321',  'bob@bob.com'],
    'cat': ['654-543-2345', 'cat@cat.com']
}

name = raw_input('enter name: ')
action = raw_input('enter 0 for ph# or 1 for email: ')

print(phone_book['%s']['%d']) % (name, action)
```

The code above is what I need help with.

My goal is to be able to enter a person's name and whether they would like to call the person's phone number, email address or both by using the raw_input which will be entered by the user. Unfortunately, every time I run the code, I get the following error:

```
    enter name:  bob
    enter 0 for ph# or 1 for email:  1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(phone_book['%s']['%d']) % (name, action)
KeyError: '%s'
exited with non-zero status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go like this:

```
print(phone_book[name][int(action)])
```

Indices must be integer and calling dict key can be done straight form variable as it will read its contents.

Answer (score 3):

You are applying the `%` operator to the wrong thing, and it isn't really going to do what you wanted to achieve.

You are asking Python to do this:

```
(*some expression*) % (name, action)
```

where *some expression* is `phone_book['%s']['%d']`, so Python executes *that part first*. So Python breaks that down further, to execute `phone_book['%s']` first and apply `['%d']` to the result. And to execute `phone_book['%s']` first means to pass the string `'%s'` to the `phone_book` dictionary. There is no such key there of course. Python never gets to applying the `%` operator to the result of course, an exception has been raised before it got there.

All this means is that you can't apply `%` printf style formatting to something that is not a single string. You have multiple strings, so you'd need to apply the formatting *to each string separately*:

```
print phone_book['%s' % name]['%d' % action]
```

But `name` is *already* a string, so using `'%s'` to turn it into a string is.. redundant. Just pass it in directly:

```
print phone_book[name]['%d' % action]
```

Using `'%d' % action` is also the wrong thing to do. String formatting *still produces a string*, all `%d` does is help you format a numeric *input* nicely, so it lets you turn a integer into a string. You want something different, you want to turn the string `action` into an integer, so *going the other way around*. You can do that with the `int()` function:

```
print phone_book[name][int(action)]
```

This then, does what you originally wanted. Note that the `%` operator is nowhere to be seen anymore! Only use that operator to format string *output*, not to process input.